# Migrate DB from one server Fedora 28 to another Fedora 37

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-migration, fedora

I try to migrate DB from fedora 28 to Fedora 37

I made "mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > vse.sql"

already done, good.

After copying to new server - I tried to import by command " mysql -u root -p < /vse.sql"

but there is everytime same mistake "ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 996: Table 'user' already exists"

if I tried this by phpMyAdmin -> same result...

how to force this to overwrite table users with my imported file

I want to migrate all from server one to server two and I dont find another better tool

Comment: only one thing was successfull - to install phpMyAdmin and removw DB mysql manually from new server and same time when I was still logged - to copy new data by phpMyAdmin importing.....it is not right, but solving situation...not very well...there must be better way

Answer (score 0):

Adding `--add-drop-table` to your `mysqldump` command will generate an export that drops any existing tables that might conflict. **This should be used with caution** - you'll want to double-check why your new server already has a `user` table before you go around deleting it.

Comment: It is not working ;-( same problem as before
I have added parameter "--add-drop-table" to mysqldump but after using on new server same result
mysql -u root -p < /vse.sql
Enter password:
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 996: Table 'user' already exists